# conditional expectations in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am testing a page that can have random overlays occur..

These HTML/CSS elements block the entire screen and force you to close them if they are displaying.

How do I write a Jasmine test `it("....")` , such that I can conditionally

- check for this popup on initial screen loading..
- close the popup with a `click()`
- check that indeed the popup closed

without using `expect` since this popup isn't always present, and the testcase would/could fail.

Here's what I currently have, and it fails if the dialog overlay isn't present..

**Jasmine Testcase description**

```
 describe("close header warning if opened", function () {
    it("should check for header warning", function () {
        writeTitleToLog("close header warning if opened");
        element(by.css('.header-warning-container')).isDisplayed().then(function (displayed) {
            if(displayed) {
                element(by.css('.close-container')).click();
            }
        });
    });

    it("should not have the header warning", function () {
        expect(element(by.css('.header-warning-container')).isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

**Test Output**

```
landing page
    should check for header warning, and close it - fail
    should not have the header warning, once it is closed - pass
```

Comment: What do you mean "popups"? `alert()`? And please share some code.

Comment: not a javascript alert.. but a CSS/HTML overlay

Comment: CSS/HTML overlay doesn't block JS to execute so there should be no problems with Jasmine to run its code. What the exact problem did you encountered with? Have you tried anything?

Comment: read my update.. the current test fails but doesn't give me an error message (like element not found).. it just fails.

Comment: Which one `it` fails?

Comment: the first `it` fails .. I can't understand why since there are no `expects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you.

As you are doing, use isDisplayed to get a check. Then, if the element is there. click the close. Wait for it to close. Then do your expect afterwards, still inside the if block, to make sure it closed. This shouldn't fail if the warning is not present, because it will skip over the expect.

```
    overlays.headerWarning.isDisplayed().then(function(result){
        if(result){
            overlays.headerWarningCloseButton.click();
            browser.wait(protractor.until.elementIsNotVisible(overlays.headerWarningCloseButton), 3000, 'Header warning overlay did not close');
            expect(overlays.headerWarning.isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy('Header was displayed after attempted close');
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    });
```

Comment: it turns out, I needed to use `isPresent()` and not `isDisplayed()`

Comment: I do like your example too, though it might slow the test over `isPresent()`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out.. I cannot use `isDisplayed()` if an element is not even present.. it will throw an error.  Here is the solution that now correctly passes

```
describe("close header warning if opened", function () {

    it("should check for header warning", function () {
        writeTitleToLog("close header warning if opened");
        var headerElm = by.css('.header-warning-container');
        element(headerElm).isPresent().then(function (isPresent) {
            if(isPresent) {
                element(by.css('.close-container')).click();
            }
        });
    });

    it("should not have the header warning", function () {
        expect(element(by.css('.header-warning-container')).isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice, looks good! I was able to get isDisplayed working as a check for me even if the element was not there, but I was calling it from a page object, which has less 'validation' of sorts on whether or not the element is there. Maybe that is the difference?